# Find local max in 2d array. Python

Tags: python, arrays, local, maxima

I don't know how write it in functional programming?
I made this code in programming paradigms.
I used Moore neighborhood.

Need to find the largest value in a given two-dimensional array local maximum.
The local maximum is an element, a value which is more important than all its neighbors.

How I understand functional programming:

Use only function calls, definition of anonymous functions based on calls of other functions, recursion, special functions that implement the possibilities of functional programming; It is FORBIDDEN to use loops, conditional operators, assignment operators, control operators except return.

Programming paradigms.

```
with open("matrix.txt", "r") as file:
    txtMatrix = file.read()
    txtMatrix += "\0"
# matrix =1 3 9 3
#         2 3 2 1
#         2 5 1 7
#         1 2 3 4

counterColumn = 0
counterRow = 0
txtNumber = ""

matrix = [[]]
for i in range(len(txtMatrix)):
    if txtMatrix[i] == " " or txtMatrix[i] == "\0":
        matrix[counterRow].append(int(txtNumber))
        counterColumn += 1
        txtNumber = ""
    elif txtMatrix[i] == "\n":
        matrix[counterRow].append(int(txtNumber))
        matrix.append([])
        counterRow += 1
        counterColumn = 0
        txtNumber = ""
    else:
        txtNumber += txtMatrix[i]

print(matrix)

localMax = []
maxInLocalMax = matrix[0][0]
print("Local maxes:")
for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
        localMax.append(matrix[i][j])
        #RU Соседство определяется по окрестности Мура
        #ENG Neighborhood is determined by the neighborhood of Moore
        for k in range(-1, 2):
            if (i == 0 and k == -1) or (i == len(matrix) - 1 and k == 1): continue
            for l in range(-1, 2):
                if (j == 0 and l == -1) or (j == len(matrix[i]) - 1 and l == 1): continue
                if localMax[len(localMax) - 1] < matrix[i + k][j + l]:
                    localMax[len(localMax) - 1] = matrix[i + k][j + l]

        print(localMax[len(localMax) - 1], end=' ')
        if maxInLocalMax < localMax[len(localMax) - 1]: maxInLocalMax = localMax[len(localMax) -1]
    print()

# print("Max in localMax: " )#, end=''
# print(maxInLocalMax)

#Output:
#Local maxes:
#3 9 9 9 
#5 9 9 9 
#5 5 7 7 
#5 5 7 7
```

I tried to make a code in functional programming but it's not so correct.

```
# Function to find minimum and maximum position in list
def maxminposition(A, n):
   # inbuilt function to find the position of minimum 
   minposition = A.index(min(A))
   # inbuilt function to find the position of maximum 
   maxposition = A.index(max(A)) 
   print ("The maximum is at position::", maxposition + 1) 
   print ("The minimum is at position::", minposition + 1)
# Driver code
A=list()
n=int(input("Enter the size of the List ::"))
print("Enter the Element ::")
for i in range(int(n)):
   k=int(input(""))
   A.append(k)
maxminposition(A,n)
```

Comment: You might forbid loop statements and conditional statements in a pure functional language, but you certainly need loop operators and conditional operators (as in list comprehensions).

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"it's not so correct" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me how to write in functional programming” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You've made a reasonable start, but you need to focus your question.

Comment: @Prune My problem that I can't understand how to read 2d array from file and find local max without using loop and the above listed things in functional programming.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: you are stuck at the "I can't understand" phase; this is an instance of [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/).  This is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis within the functional paradigm.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune Ok, I have one more question, can I use loop in functional programming?
My task was just to find local max and I choose Moore neighborhood as a cool example.

Comment: Generally not: instead, you use recursion to iterate through a sequence, constructing a new sequence as you return from each call.  This is covered in recursion tutuorials.

Comment: There is more than one way to phrase a solution, but one functional approach is to use divide and conquer in this way: the maximum of an array is just the one element, if there is only one element, otherwise there is more than one element, and the maximum is the greater of the maximum of one half and the maximum of the other half. You can split the array left and right, if it is wider than it is tall; otherwise you can split top and bottom.

Comment: Also, conceptual questions about functional programming are off topic here; try cs.stackexchange.com instead.